# Node: How to Convert JSON to Markdown

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi gouys I would like to create makdown file from JSON object ?

For example, If I have json array like this:

```
[{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
},
{
"name":"Tim",
"age":20,
"cars":[ "Ford", "Mercedes" ]
}]
```

How would I write this into a Markdown file and save, should I create a template ? Could You provide me same code samples ? Also I wold not like to use existing libraries like json2md etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I have accomplished it:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const arr = [{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
},
{
"name":"Tim",
"age":20,
"cars":[ "Ford", "Mercedes" ]
}]

fs.writeFile(output, JSON.stringify(arr), (err: any) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return;
      }
});
```

Comment: No Markdown in that, you are writing out a javascript object as a string to a file .

Comment: @OlivierHenley that is what I was trying to accomplish in first place

Answer (score 1):

(posting answer because I can't comment yet)

There isn't enough information in the question for a full answer. You are reading a fairly complex object and you need to decide how to display it. Write an example in markdown and view it, then you will have a sample of what you want to do. I'm not even sure that you can represent this in markdown

Once you have figured out exactly what you want, you can follow an algorithm such as

- read your file and convert json to a Javascript object (JSON. parse() for example). You will then have an array
- iterate over the elements of the array. For each element, write out the markdown as you did for the sample

Comment: If you put the effort, the question is quite clear actually. Dont you see the inherent format structure of a json object? Any json object could be unroll as nested lists with leaves being key value elements. Generating such nested lists in markdown format would be super useful for quick presentation purposes. (Eg. sending a json object message to a telegram bot which formats using markdown)